# CSS standardized padding

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.form td:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 15px;
} 

.form td:first-child {
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.form td:last-child {
    padding-right: 5px;
}

input,select {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and my HTML is:

```
<table class="form">
    <tr>
        <td><input value="foo" /></td>
        <td><input value="bar" /></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>nono1</option>
                <option>nono2</option>
                <option>nono3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input value="foo2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="foo2" /></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>nono1</option>
                <option>nono2</option>
                <option>nono3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input value="foobar2" /></td>
        <td><input value="foo22" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8tKP6/)

That will produce something like this:
[image]

How fit `select` with the exact size of `input` elements?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to use `:not(:last-child)` here.  `td { padding-right: 15px } td:last-child { padding-right: 5px }` does the same thing as what you already have.  Also, it appears as though you're using tables for layout, have you seen the `columns` property? http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/tprDw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
input,select {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This works on all browsers and on IE8+. Firefox needs `-moz`, old Chromes and Safari up to 5.x needs `-webkit`. See more in http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Comment: With the last edit solved the problem! I lost a few hours with this issue, thanks! I will accept as correct answer in 5 minutes.